# Canon EDSDK.EdsGetImage error EDS_ERR_NOT_SUPPORTED when reading CR2 file

Tags: canon-sdk

I'm trying to read a CR2 file using the Canon EDSDKv0309W. I didn't found an example for this SDK version so I looked at several examples from older versions and created the code below. But I always get EDS_ERR_NOT_SUPPORTED in line    EDSDK.EdsGetImage(..).

Using a 32Bit compilation under .Net4.6.1 I can read the correct with and height from images taken with EOS500D and M100. But I don't get the image. So my assumption is I get a wrong pointer from EdsCreateMemoryStream. But I don't see what is wrong and how to debug this. 
Any help will be appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using EDSDKLib;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace CR2Reader
{
class Program
{

    static Bitmap GetImage(IntPtr img_stream, EDSDK.EdsImageSource imageSource)
    {
        IntPtr stream = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr img_ref = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr streamPointer = IntPtr.Zero;
        EDSDK.EdsImageInfo imageInfo;
        uint error = 0;

        try
        {
            //create reference and get image info
            error = EDSDK.EdsCreateImageRef(img_stream, out img_ref);
            if (error == 0)
            {
                error = EDSDK.EdsGetImageInfo(img_ref, imageSource, out imageInfo);
                if (error == 0)
                {
                    EDSDK.EdsSize outputSize = new EDSDK.EdsSize();
                    outputSize.width = imageInfo.EffectiveRect.width;
                    outputSize.height = imageInfo.EffectiveRect.height;
                    //calculate amount of data
                    int datalength = outputSize.height * outputSize.width * (int)imageInfo.NumOfComponents * (int)(imageInfo.ComponentDepth / 8);
                    //create buffer that stores the image
                    error = EDSDK.EdsCreateMemoryStream((ulong)datalength, out stream);
                    if (error == 0)
                    {
                        //load image into the buffer
                        error = EDSDK.EdsGetImage(img_ref, imageSource, EDSDK.EdsTargetImageType.RGB16, imageInfo.EffectiveRect, outputSize, stream);
                        if (error == 0)
                        {
                            //make BGR from RGB (System.Drawing (i.e. GDI+) uses BGR)
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[datalength];

                            unsafe
                            {
                                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(stream, buffer, 0, datalength);
                                byte tmp;
                                fixed (byte* pix = buffer)
                                {
                                    for (int i = 0; i < datalength; i += 3)
                                    {
                                        tmp = pix[i];        //Save B value
                                        pix[i] = pix[i + 2]; //Set B value with R value
                                        pix[i + 2] = tmp;    //Set R value with B value
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            //Get pointer to stream
                            error = EDSDK.EdsGetPointer(stream, out streamPointer);
                            if (error == 0)
                            {
                                //Create bitmap with the data in the buffer
                                return new Bitmap(outputSize.width, outputSize.height, datalength, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, streamPointer);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            //Release all data
            if (img_ref != IntPtr.Zero) error = EDSDK.EdsRelease(img_ref);
            if (stream != IntPtr.Zero) error = EDSDK.EdsRelease(stream);
        }
    }

   static Bitmap ReadCR2Image(string fileName)
    {
        IntPtr outStream = new IntPtr();

        uint error = EDSDK.EdsInitializeSDK();

        error += EDSDK.EdsCreateFileStream(fileName,
                     EDSDK.EdsFileCreateDisposition.OpenExisting,
                     EDSDK.EdsAccess.Read,
                     out outStream);
        Bitmap bmp = null;
        if (error == 0)
        {
            bmp = GetImage(outStream, EDSDK.EdsImageSource.FullView);
        }
        if (outStream != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            error = EDSDK.EdsRelease(outStream);
        }
        EDSDK.EdsTerminateSDK();
        return bmp;
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = ReadCR2Image("IMG_3113.CR2");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong `EdsImageSource` type.
Since you are loading a RAW image you also have to use `EdsImageSource.RAWFullView`. `EdsImageSource.FullView` would be appropriate for e.g. a JPG or TIFF.

Once you change that, everything should work just fine.

**Edit:** just saw you are using `RGB16` as target but the rest of the code assumes normal 8bit RGB. You'll have to change a whole bunch of stuff to get that working correctly. I'd advise you to use `RGB` unless you really need 16bit.

**Edit 2:** Looks like the library is a bit out of that in that regard (I should really update it). In any case, you can always check the header files of the SDK for up-to-date values. Here's the current definition for `EdsImageSource`:

```
enum EdsImageSource
{
    FullView = 0,
    Thumbnail,
    Preview,
    RAWThumbnail,
    RAWFullView,
}
```

As for changes required for 16bit:

- `datalength` is incorrect
- you're using `byte` instead of `ushort` to set the pixels
- you create the `Bitmap` with `PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb`
- then there's another thing where `Bitmap` doesn't fully support 16Bit. See [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/482727/GDIplus-Deep-Color-Workaround) for some in-depth information.

Depending on what you need to do it's probably better to either use the raw pixel data directly as you get it from the SDK or use a different graphics library (e.g. WPF, SkiaSharp, ImageSharp, etc.)

Comment: I  don't have this option. The enum is:  public enum EdsImageSource : uint
        {
            FullView = 0   ,
            Thumbnail,
            Preview,
        }

Comment: Yes, I need RGB16. I have an application I process TIFF16. At the moment I convert CR2 to Tiff16 and want to read the CR2 directly. What do you mean with "I have to change a whole bunch"? If you mean the code below the line that produce the error, yes, this is from an example I found -> PixelFormat.Format48bppRgb, but I don't came to these lines...

Comment: @Inok I made another edit with details to your new questions.

Comment: Using your definiton of EdsImageSource I can call EdsGetImage successfully. Now at Marshal.Copy I get a AccessViolationException, perhaps because of the data length, but the documentation of EdsCreateMemoryStream says inBufferSize in byte. So far from my understanding the stream has amount of data [in byte]: h*w*3(colors)*16(Bit)/2. To copy the stream in a buffer I need a byte buffer with the same size. Is my understanding wrong?

Comment: Concerning bmp: In my application I use my own class to process raw data, as soon I have the databuffer I don't need the conversion to bitmap. I will fill my data class directly. I think these lines of code are even from your example in codeproject (thanks for this). The idea of the bitmap is only to check if the reading is generally working.

Comment: @Inok the `datalength` is correct that way yes, but you are trying to copy the stream object not the stream data. Use `EdsGetPointer` to get a pointer to the data. Also, you could use `EdsCreateMemoryStreamFromPointer` where you pass in the a byte array, then you don't have to do a copy afterwards. If you just want to check if the image is there, you could use an 8bit image and just compress the 16bit values to 8bit.